# best way to make vertical scroll like in the image

Tags: android, scrollview, android-imagebutton

![I am trying to make similar vertical scroll view as in first screenshot. Its an app of Itaca. I'm doing this this using ImageButton. Please let me know the best way to get the result. Thanks in advance.

`

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/backg" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#006BB2" >


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/homeicon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/company"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/homeicon1" />

           
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU444.jpg)

[image: The second image is the result which I get using the above code]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is for helping you with problems in your code, _not_ something where you post your wishes and someone does the work for you.

Comment: I just want to know the best way to stick the up and down arrow icons as shown in the link here: http://postimg.org/image/6aqwaluzl/

Answer (score 0):

Add `RelativeLayout` as a parent layout.

1. add yout child `ScrollView` with 2 `ImageButton`.
2. add your other `ImageView`

Comment: I'm unable to fix the 2 arrow images at the top and bottom of scrollview. I think I need to add the scrollview to another Linear Layout to involve the 2 arrow icons. Like:

Relative Layout as parent layout
Then a Linear Layout to add 2 arrow images
Insert ScrollView inside Linear Layout and add imagebuttons